# Set BitmapDrawable resource in constructor

Tags: android, resources, drawable

How can I set a resource in a `BitmapDrawable` constructor? In the example below I want to set the resource to `R.drawable.default_fb_pic`, which is an ID, not a resource. How can I get the resource?
With an `ImageView` we can set the resource with its ID:

```
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);
```

I'm not very clear with why sometimes the resource can be set directly with its ID, and sometimes not.

Anybody can help?

```
static class DownloadedDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {            

    public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
        super(R.drawable.default_fb_pic); //"The constructor BitmapDrawable(int)
        //is undefined",
        //which I understand because it takes a resource.
        //But how do I get the resource and why is there no constructor
        //directly with the id?
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is

```
Context.getResources()
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29)

And you can chain it with

```
getDrawable()
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29)

```
mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_fb_pic);
```

You just need a reference to your context.

Comment: If i am at the place where context is not available then how i can set the Bitmap from resource id ( I have derived BitmapDrawable)

Comment: You'll have to pass in the context, or get the drawable where you do have context and pass the drawable in. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192886/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-outside-of-an-activity/9193028#9193028

Answer (score 3):

getResources().getDrawble(int id) was already depreciated in API 22. it is highly recommended to use contextCompat.getDrawble(Context ctx, int id) instead.