# How do I use sharedPreferences outside of an Activity?

Tags: android, mvvm

I've been stuck on this very simple problem for hours now and Ive been unable to find any suitable solutions through google.

I am trying to use the SharedPreferences class in the model layer of my application. Specifically I want to be able to save or fetch the user name and the corresponding token whenever the application is started(if the user sets the application up for auto login that is).

Is there a way for me to use SharedPreferences for this issue or am I forced into using FileInput/Output ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Where do you instantiate your Model class?

Just pass either a context or the SharedPreferences to the constructor:

```java
public class Model {
    private final Context context;
    private final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    public Model(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("name", 0);
    }

    private String doSomething(){
        return sharedPrefs.getString("key", "defValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright. But doesnt that pose an issue if I want to access this data from more than one activity?

Comment: If you accessed the data from more than one activity, you would use a new constructor you mean? If you want the same SharedPreferences across activity it's just dependant on the 'name'.

Comment: Thank you. This ended up being key in solving my problem.

Comment: Explained here http://www.freakyjolly.com/shared-preference-context-error-android/

Answer (score 5):

`SharedPreferences` isn't called only from `Activity`, but from `Context` (which `Activity` extends) so you can use the application context as well.

Comment: I also developerd small injection library, which allows easier use fo preferences: https://github.com/ko5tik/andject  You can just inject / eject  preferences into bean properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPrederences from any code that holds a Context. From the Activity documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html:

> Activity persistent state is managed with the method getPreferences(int), allowing you
>       to retrieve and modify a set of name/value pairs associated with the activity. To use
>       preferences that are shared across multiple application components (activities,
>       receivers, services, providers), you can use the underlying Context.getSharedPreferences()
>       method to retrieve a preferences object stored under a specific name. (Note that it is
>       not possible to share settings data across application packages -- for that you will
>       need a content provider.)