# shared preferences from different class not working

Tags: java, android

While I defined sharedpreference in a separate class outside an activity, It is throwing exception. But, the same method when I declared with in the activity it is working just fine.

I understand activity supposed to be started first before we call getshared preferences.

code as below:

```
sharedpreferencesutil.java
android.content.SharedPreferences prefs =
            getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_NAME,
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
    android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
public boolean savePassword(String password) {
        editor.putString(Constants.PASSWORD, password);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return prefs.getString(Constants.PASSWORD, null);
    }



Activity class:

mUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextUsername);
if(sharedPreferences.getUserNameFromPrefs().isEmpty()) {
        mUserName.setText(sharedPreferences.getUserNameFromPrefs(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
}
```

I tried using context also but still I am getting runtime nullpointer exception on getSharedPref method in my activity class.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

These 2 links answers your question clearly.

[Android - How to use SharedPreferences in non-Activity class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491287/android-how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-non-activity-class)

[How do I use sharedPreferences outside of an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192886/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-outside-of-an-activity)

SharedPreferenced works only with a valid activity context. You can simply pass the context as a parameter to your class and this would solve your issue.