# Android saving highscores with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm pretty new to android dev. I'm creating a game that has a framework, a framework implementation and the main game.

I wanna save my highscores.
Scores are saved in `Projectile.HowManyHits` which is also the class that shoot the missiles.
extends `Activity` is run from `Framework.implementation.AndroidGame`.

From what i understand is that `SharedPrefs` has to be run from within Activity because its a part of Context.

I've created a new class that is named: Scores. In this class I wanna run the save or get function for the highscores.

When I don't use `extends activity` (or `Application`) it will not recognize the `getSharedPreferences` or `MODE_PRIVATE`.

So the main question is: how do I create a class that handles the saving to the SharedPreferences and how can I run inside GameScreen (this is where the whole game is drawn etc.) a call to the method to go and Save the Highscore.

Comment: Can you include the relevant code that you have?  That will help us point you in the right direction.

Comment: For an example of a game that saves high scores in SharedPreferences, see Android Breakout (https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/).  It gets updated from GameActivity.  The game itself runs on a separate non-Activity thread via `GLSurfaceView`, so it gets latched at certain times.  Whther or not you'd need to do something similar depends on how your game is structured.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have "*searched the shit out of google*" very well, next time get some waders.

[How do I use sharedPreferences outside of an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192886/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-outside-of-an-activity/9193028#9193028)

```
public class Model {

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    public Model(Context context) {
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("name", 0);
    }

    private String doSomething(){
        return sharedPrefs.getString("key", "defValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that article about the model class.
I've fixed the problem with the example from Android BreakoutGame.
Included the right code in the AndroidGame.java (where Activity is called).
Thx Fadden.